# How can i get the specific value that clicked on the button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem regarding getting the value on the specific table row, when I click the first button they get all the value. however when I click the second button itself value show

**Goal: I want to get the value of price on specific table row.**

[image: Output]

**I have here the my Click function**

```
$("button.removeorderWithCondi").on("click", function() {


     var parent = $(this).closest(".condimentParent");
     var get_parent_price  = $(this).closest("tr").find(".total").text();

     console.log(get_parent_price);


});
```

**Problem:**

[image: Output problem]

Comment: Show your HTML code

Answer (score 1):

Potentially a better option is to strongly associate the value with the button, instead of relying on a HTML structure that may or may not change. You can use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for this. This also has the advantage that you can use the raw values if the display values are formatted.

You would have something like the following:

```js
$("button.removeorderWithCondi").on("click", function() {
     var price  = $(this).data("value");
     console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="removeorderWithCondi" data-value="5.00">Delete</button>
```

The downside of this approach is you have to refactor what is generating the table in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your html table will be in this structure ,Hope this solves your problem,thanks

```js
$('.getprice').click(function(e){
console.log($(this).parent().prev().text())
})
```

```css
td
{
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td><button class="getprice">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0.00</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0.00</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>50</td>
<td><button class="getprice">Click</button></td>
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```